# Master/Detail in ASP.NET MVC with two HTML tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a master and details view in ASP.NET MVC.

I want to create a view with two tables, such that the first table will load a list of people, and clicking on the select link will load details of the selected person to the second table.

In WebForms, this is easy for me, but with MVC, I don't have any joy.

I have successfully loaded the first, but I am lost with what to do with the second. I have tried to use JavaScript as I did with the cascading dropdownlist, still not working.

@Agramer I am adding some code now, I followed @Shiyju lead and got this far.

```
<table id="Pat" class="table table-condensed table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Salutation
            </th>
            <th> Surname</th> 
            <th> Firstname</th>
            <th> Reg. No.</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var lst in lstPat)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => lst.salutation.Salute)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => lst.Surname)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => lst.Firstname)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => lst.RegNo)
                </td>
                <th>
                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick="pickdet(@lst.PatientID)">
                        @*<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>*@
                        <i class="fa fa-list fa-lg"></i>  Select
                    </button>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-alert" onclick="location.href ='@Url.Action("Create", "PVSigns1", new { id = lst.PatientID })'">
                        @*<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>*@
                        <i class="fa fa-list fa-lg"></i>  Create New
                    </button>
                     &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "PVSigns1", new { id = lst.PatientID })'">
                        <span class="fa fa-edit fa-lg"></span>  Edit 
                    </button>
                </th>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<div>
    <h3> Details</h3>
    <table id="Pv" class="table table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Sign</td>
                <td> Value </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var pvv in lstPv)
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => pvv.VitalSigns.Sign);
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => pvv.SignValue);
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The JavaScript to attempt filling the table

```
 function pickdet(Id){
        var url = "/PVSigns1/GetDetails";
        $.post(url, {Id: Id})
        .done(function (response) {
            $("#Pv").html(response);
        });
    }
```

It is actually pulling the results but not putting them into the table result set as seen below.

```
PVC120HBC150Pulse72
```

Comment: You want to show the details in the same page as the list of people ?

Comment: Could you show the code you have at the moment?

Comment: @Shyju Yes I want to show the details on the same page. The details table will be below the master table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax to get the details about the person record which was clicked. Listen to the click event on the anchor tag, get the unique id of the person and make an ajax call to server with this id and let your server returns the details of the person. In your ajax call's success/done event, parse the response coming back and show that as needed.

Something like this

```
@model IEnumerable<Person>
<table>
  <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
  @foreach(var p in Model)
  {
    <tr>
       <td>@Html.ActionLink(p.Name,"Details","Person",
                                     new {@id=p.Id},new {class="personLink"})</td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
<h2>Details of selected person:</h2>
<div id="fullName"></div>
<div id="jobTitle"></div>
```

and the javascript to handle the click event is

```
$(funtion(){
   $("a.personLink").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      var url=$(this).attr("href");
      $.getJSON(url,function(data){
         if(data!=null)
         {
           $("#fullName").text(data.FullName);
           $("#jobTitle").text(data.JobTitle);
         }
      });     
   });    
});
```

Assuming your `Details` action method in your `PersonController` accepts an id(of person) and return an object with `FullName` and `JobTitle` property

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
  var d=new {FullName="Shyju", JobTitle="Developer"};
  // Hard coded for demo. You may get this information from db
  return Json(d,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

You may also consider returning a partial view result (the html markup you want to render in the details view) instead of returning JSON data. In that case, instead of reading each property value from the response, you may simply set the response(html markup of details) as the inner html of the container div. You may use the jquery `html(someString)` for that.

Comment: Thanks, this is good, but I want to display all the details in a another table.

Comment: You can update the markup as needed. You can also consider returning a partial view as explained in the last part of the answer.